# C# equivalent to php mysql_real_escape_string function?

Tags: c#, php, c#-4.0

C# equivalent to php mysql_real_escape_string function or similar function?

mysql_real_escape_string() calls MySQL's library function mysql_real_escape_string, which prepends backslashes to the following characters: \x00, \n, \r, \, ', " and \x1a.

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020373/escaping-values-in-sql-queries-c-with-sql-connector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is anything that does that, there are various encoding/escaping methods in the `System.Web.HttpUtility` class.  However if it is just those characters you want to replace you could use `string.Replace()`

e.g.

```
string test = " \x00\n";
Console.WriteLine(test.Replace("\x00","\\x00").Replace("\n","\\n"));
```

Comment: -1: This is certainly not the equivalent of `mysql_real_escape_string`. If it were, we 'd all be using `addslashes` or some such.

Comment: I have no idea what mysql_real_escape_string does other than the description supplied by the OP, thus i have supplied a solution that matches his description.  Notice i frame the answer "if it is just those characters you want to replace"...

Comment: @Jon i just had a quick look at the PHP manual and it says mysql_real_escape_string works as the OP describes.  In fact as far as i can tell from the manual the difference between addslashes and mysql_real_escape_string is the the latter also escapes \n \r and \x1a.  If there are other differences please feel free to explain them.

Comment: [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) takes the MySQL connection encoding into account (it says so in the very first line). Contrast this with [`mysql_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php), which is the equivalent of `string.Replace`, works exactly like you describe and has been deprecated because it is unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

I use this function:

```
public static string MySQLEscape(string str)
{
    return Regex.Replace(str, @"[\x00'""\b\n\r\t\cZ\\%_]",
        delegate(Match match)
        {
            string v = match.Value;
            switch (v)
            {
                case "\x00":            // ASCII NUL (0x00) character
                    return "\\0";   
                case "\b":              // BACKSPACE character
                    return "\\b";
                case "\n":              // NEWLINE (linefeed) character
                    return "\\n";
                case "\r":              // CARRIAGE RETURN character
                    return "\\r";
                case "\t":              // TAB
                    return "\\t";
                case "\u001A":          // Ctrl-Z
                    return "\\Z";
                default:
                    return "\\" + v;
            }
        });
}
```