# c#.net Regex - Need to find a sequence of characters, then replace one character within it

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to build a regex that can look for names that contain apostrophes (O'Connor, O'Neil) and replace the apostrophes with 2 apostrophes (O''Connor, O''Neil).

I don't want to do this with all apostrophes in the string in question, just apostrophes that appear between two letters (upper or lower case). Now, I have no trouble finding instances of LETTER-APOSTROPHE-LETTER, but I'm not sure how to take that sequence and change the `'` to `''`.

Comment: I have a bad feeling about this...

Comment: @jnylen - Not very helpful, care to elaborate please??

Comment: Are you trying to escape characters for a database query, or something similar?

Comment: Exactly, mySQL doesn't like single quotes

Comment: Don't do this - use the native methods for your DB that handle this exact situation, and many more that you haven't thought of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new Regex("([a-zA-Z])'([a-zA-Z])").Replace(input, match => match.Groups[1] + "''" + match.Groups[2])
```

Comment: This deletes the O and the C in O'Connor. I end up with ''onnor

Comment: Strange, `new Regex("([a-zA-Z])'([a-zA-Z])").Replace("O'Connor", match => match.Groups[1] + "''" + match.Groups[2])` returns `O''Connor` to me..

Comment: My mistake, works fine! Just a little slip up on my end. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7):

You said this is for inserting values into a database.  Don't do this - use parameterized queries instead, which will handle escaping properly.  [Jon Skeet says so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2020393/106302).

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into this. I'm sure it will help in the future. Unfortunately, right now I don't have direct access to the DB insertion method as they are on the server. I'm processing strings and passing them to a web service. But in the end, yes, they do end up in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

```
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=[^'])(')(?=[^'])", "''");
```

Comment: I prefer your method. It matches the apostrophe exactly using lookahead and lookbehind constructs, but I think you should replace the [^'] with [a-zA-Z] since it has to be a name, so no numbers or symbols.

Answer (score 0):

This will work, I just tested it:

```
Regex.Replace("(\w)'(\w)","$1''$2");
```

(O'Connor, O'Neil) turns into (O''Connor, O''Neil)

Comment: Parameterized queries are definitely the better route, I'd go with that.  This Regex solves your Regex question.