# Vb.net Mysql: Escape String

Tags: mysql, vb.net, prepared-statement, mysql-real-escape-string

This is a realy quick question

One way to update or insert data in a database is to use prepared statements like this:

```
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("UPDATE `table` SET `field` = ?value", con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?value", "user given value")
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

One would do that to prevent any chances of SQL injections. my question is if i use the mysqlHelper Class to escaps strings. It it equalivant to prepared statements? In other words is SQL injection still possible?

**Here is how i use the escape character method**

```
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("UPDATE `table` SET `field` =" & MySqlHelper.EscapeString("user given value"),con)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does but generally your better off doing it the proper way by using parameters. Using the above is just not advised.

[Have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020373/escaping-values-in-sql-queries-c-with-sql-connector)