# Best place to use MySqlHelper.EscapeString

Tags: c#, mysql, class, constructor

Is it normal practice to use the MySqlHelper.EscapeString in a class constructor to remove any unwanted characters?

Or are their better alternatives to accomplish this.

Basically I have the following class

```
public class Region
{
     public int RegionId {get;set;}
     public string Name {get;set;}
     public string Area {get;set;}
}
```

I only want to use MySqlHelper.EscapeString on the properties of Name and Area, when these properties are assigned data.

This class is then added to a list like

```
List<Region> MyRegionList = new List<Region>();
```

Should I use MySqlHelper.EscapeString by iterating through the entire list ?  Once the list is formatted, I'm wanting to get it into a comma separated style so I use;

```
var sRegionList = String.Join(",", MyRegionList.Select(m => String.Format("({0},'{1}','{2}')", m.RegionId, m.Name, m.Area)));
```

Comment: IMO, allowing an implementation detail such as SQL (escaping) to leak into your object model is a mistake.

Comment: 100% agree with @KirkWoll.

Comment: Also, see the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020373/escaping-values-in-sql-queries-c-with-sql-connector

Comment: If I had a list of Regions like List<Region> MyRegionList = new List<Region>(); how would you apply MySqlHelper.EscapeString ?  A simple loop around the list ?

Comment: Do you need any additional information ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use MySqlHelper.EscapeString I just applied it directly to the lambda statement like below

```
var sRegionList = String.Join(",", MyRegionList.Select(m => String.Format("({0},'{1}','{2}')", m.RegionId, MySqlHelper.EscapeString(m.Name), MySqlHelper.EscapeString(m.Area))));
```